# Do variables initialized in the override ApplicationContextAware.setApplicationContext method need to be declared as volatile in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, applicationcontext

I initialize SpringUtils class Spring singleton bean applicationContext field by override ApplicationContextAware.setApplicationContext method:

```java
@Component
public class SpringUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    /**
     * get applicationContext
     *
     * @return ApplicationContext
     */
    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Should I worry about SpringUtils class Spring singleton bean applicationContext field visibility to other beans(other thread) and mark it volatile.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a getter method that actually retrieves the `ApplicationContext` then any other Spring-managed Bean with access to `SpringUtils` (by dependency injection) may have access to `ApplicationContext` via `SpringUtils`, but any other Spring-managed Bean can also get a hold of `ApplicationContext` on its own so I would say you ara just overthinking this.

Comment: But sometimes a bean map(private Map beanMap，not declare as volatile） is initialized in setApplicationContext,the beanMap is  safe publication?Other Spring-managed Bean access to beanMap can see latest value instead of stale null?

Comment: Yes, `ApplicationContext` is a living thing. You will "see" the changes on it.